# Hover over tooltip in leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I am using Vue-Leaflet.

I have a link in my leaflet tooltip when hovering over a marker. But I am unable to click the link because as soon as the cursor moves off the marker the mouseout fires and the tooltip disappears.

Is there a way to control the leaflet tooltip so that it doesn't close if the cursor is still hovering over the tooltip so that I can click the link?

https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LTooltip.html

```html
<l-map
  ref="map"
  :options="{ attributionControl: false }"
>
  <l-tile-layer :url="mapData.url" />
  <l-marker
    v-for="(item, index) in mapData.markers"
    :key="index"
    :lat-lng="item.position"
  >
    <l-tooltip :options="{ interactive: true }">
      <router-link  :to="item.link">
        <span>{{ item.link }}</span>
      </router-link>
    </l-tooltip>   
  </l-marker>
</l-map>
```

Comment: You could either use a `@click` event to set something here. Otherwise, there is the [`permanent`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip-option) option available. Is this suiting your needs?

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure that this one will be reactive afterwards: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/

Comment: Not quite. Permanent will make all the marker tooltips open on page load.

Comment: Does it work if you use a `@click` + debounce maybe?

Comment: I want to be able to just hover over the marker, and then click on a link in the tooltip. There is a popup component within leaflet that lets you click on a marker and then I could click the link in the popup. But I need to have it render on hover.